# serving static assets via http is really slow compared to sshfs (apache2/nginx)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, static-content, static-files

After migrating to a new VPS I had some users complaining about slow loading images on their sites. After creating some test files with dd I realized that I can download all files via sshfs with full speed while downloads via web are painfully slow. The larger the file is and the longer the transfer takes, the slower the transfer speed gets.

I thought I had some problems with Apache and just spend the whole evening with replacing Apache2 against nginx for static file serving - with no effect at all.

No I/O wait states in top. Tons of RAM free, no high CPU utilization and hdparm shows a decent I/O performance at all times.

I just have no idea anymore, what's happening on this server.

This is a link to a demo file: http://master.dealux.de/file.tgz

Anybody an idea what I can check out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change your VPS, you also change your data center ?

Maybe your clients / users are too long.

I can donwload from netherlands your file:

wget master.dealux.de/file.tgz
--2013-06-28 01:46:04--  master.dealux.de/file.tgz
Resolving master.dealux.de... 46.105.15.7
Connecting to master.dealux.de|46.105.15.7|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 500000000 (477M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: âfile.tgzâ

100%[======================================>] 500,000,000 8.50M/s   in 90s

2013-06-28 01:47:34 (5.32 MB/s) - âfile.tgzâ

**Also from USA**

wget master.dealux.de/file.tgz
--2013-06-27 19:50:00--  http://master.dealux.de/file.tgz
Resolving master.dealux.de... 46.105.15.7
Connecting to master.dealux.de|46.105.15.7|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 500000000 (477M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: âfile.tgzâ

100%[======================================>] 500,000,000 9.81M/s   in 90s

2013-06-27 19:51:31 (5.29 MB/s) - âfile.tgzâ

And I cant test from 4 locations more and for me the speed is OK, maybe on some hours the red of VPS is slow, or have bad conections whit some locations.

Comment: Thank's for testing. You must be right. I also checked from several locations and it was slow from all servers. Must be some load problems on the host I guess.

It's the same provider. Datacenter could be a different one.